# Better option for String Manipulation - .NET

Tags: c#, string

I'm working with huge `string` data for a project in C#. I'm confused about which approach should I use to manipulate my `string` data.

First Approach:

```
StringBuilder myString = new StringBuilder().Append(' ', 1024);

while(someString[++counter] != someChar)
    myString[i++] += someString[counter];
```

Second Approach:

```
String myString = new String();

int i = counter;
while(soumeString[++counter] != someChar);
myString = someString.SubString(i, counter - i);
```

Which one of the two would be more fast(and efficient)? Considering the strings I'm working with are huge.

The strings are already in the `RAM`.
The size of the string can vary from 32MB-1GB.

Comment: `myString.Append(someString[counter]);`, with the `StringBuilder` version

Comment: If only there were a way to test it...

Comment: You can test it by creating a timer for each method

Comment: 4kiB, 200kiB, 4MiB? 20GiB? I'd use a different approach for each.

Comment: like about, 32MB-1GB. The size is variable. @JonHanna

Comment: Then I'd use a stream solution as per Tim's answer (which really has nothing to do with regexes). The less you hold in memory the better, get it out to the next streaming level ASAP.

Comment: The string is already in **RAM** so there is no need to stream it from `Disk` or `HTTP`. @JonHanna

Comment: For the record, these are all things which should be stated in the post. The source of the data, the size of the data, and the desired results of a solution. Otherwise, we're just guessing.

Comment: yes @TimMedora, I agree, should I edit it?

Comment: Yes, that will help people better understand your question and provide better answers, and also makes the solution complete so that it has value to others reading it later.

Comment: Sorry for not adding that in the first place, I didn't thought about that point. @TimMedora

Comment: Always pre-allocate a large capacity StringBuilder when you know you're going to create a large string, eg `new StringBuilder(4*1024*1024)`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Per request from OP, here are my test results.

Assumptions:

- Big string is already in memory, no requirement for reading from disk
- Goal is to not use any native pointers/unsafe blocks
- The "checking" process is simple enough that something like Regex is not needed.  For now simplifying to a single char comparison.  The below code can easily be modified to consider multiple chars at once, this should have no effect on the relative performance of the two approaches.

  ```
  public static void Main()
  {
      string bigStr = GenString(100 * 1024 * 1024);

      Stopwatch sw = Stopwatch.StartNew();
      for (int i = 0; i < 10; i++)
      {
          int counter = -1;
          StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();
          while (bigStr[++counter] != 'x')
              sb.Append(bigStr[counter]);
          Console.WriteLine(sb.ToString().Length);
      }
      sw.Stop();
      Console.WriteLine("StringBuilder: {0}", sw.Elapsed.TotalSeconds);

      sw = Stopwatch.StartNew();
      for (int i = 0; i < 10; i++)
      {
          int counter = -1;
          while (bigStr[++counter] != 'x') ;

          Console.WriteLine(bigStr.Substring(0, counter).Length);
      }
      sw.Stop();
      Console.WriteLine("Substring: {0}", sw.Elapsed.TotalSeconds);
  }

  public static string GenString(int size)
  {
      StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder(size);
      for (int i = 0; i < size - 1; i++)
      {
          sb.Append('a');
      }
      sb.Append('x');
      return sb.ToString();            
  }
  ```

Results (release build, .NET 4):

**StringBuilder** ~7.9 sec

**Substring** ~1.9 sec

StringBuilder was consistently > 3x slower, with a variety of different sized strings.

Comment: Try using a bigger initial value for `new StringBuilder(n)`, otherwise it will spend all of its time resizing and copying large buffers as the string grows.

Comment: @Loadmaster - that's a good point.  I modified it to preallocate the entire string length (100 * 1024 * 1024) and it helped a bit, but `Substring` approach was still about 3x faster.

Answer (score 4):

You should use `IndexOf` rather than doing individual character manipulations in a loop, and add whole chunks of string to the result:

```
StringBuilder myString = new StringBuilder();
int pos = someString.IndexOf(someChar, counter);
myString.Append(someString.SubString(counter, pos));
```

Comment: I just tested and it is much faster to use `.IndexOf` and `.Substring` than to build up with a `StringBuilder`.  However, I don't know why you are using a `StringBuilder` here - `.SubString` returns a full-fledged `string`, ready to use.  Also, not sure what `counter` means in this code.

Comment: @latkin the `counter` is "lifted" from the second code snippet in the OP: `int i = counter`. I am using `StringBuilder.Append` because I assume that the whole string is going to be used in a loop - at least that's what I gather from the use of `counter`: he'd get to some position look for `someChar`, advance some more, then look for `someChar` again, and so on.

Comment: I was guessing that the poster wanted to do something a little fancier than just "scan to character" (e.g. scan to the next comma that isn't enclosed in quote marks) but didn't want to burden down the question with such details.  The fact that the poster's original code will throw an exception if the character is not found in the array, suggested to me that it was a simplified example.  Still, if one does just want to scan to a character, `IndexOf` is the way to do it.  Note that your code will throw a different exception in the character-not-found case.

Comment: 'counter' is the counter that keeps track of the current index. To let other methods know -which index are we at. @latkin

Comment: I can not use `IndexOf` as a approach. Why? Because there are multiple characters involved and @supercat guessed most of the part correctly.

Comment: @JakeDylan For situations when there are multiple characters involved there are regular expressions. A simple expression like `[&*#]` should be very fast, because regex builds a state machine optimized for fast searches of strings.

Comment: My point was that for the goal "Return the head substring of a big str up to some char" you don't need a stringbuilder or a counter. `bigStr.Substring(0, bigStr.IndexOf('x') + 1)` will do it.  Note the OP's `while` loop in option 2 is a one-liner (see the `;` on the end), and is just used to push `counter` to the right index to call `SubString` once.  If the predicate is more complex, then sure, a counter is needed.  Still no StringBuilder, through :)

Comment: the character 'x' you are referring to, is not the only 'x' character in the string, you are missing that point my friend. @latkin

Comment: @JakeDylan No, I'm not.  Read the second-to-last sentence of my comment.  I specifically called out that a different approach is needed for the more complex scenario.  I think you might be missing the point, in that you still have not updated your question with the myriad specific details folks need to know to give you an effective answer. (e.g. that you are matching more than a single char, as indicated by your sample code)

Comment: Nowhere in my question I state, I need an answer considering `IndexOf`, `StringBuilder` and `SubString`. Read my question again. @latkin

Comment: @latkin, the first comment of yours, remove `.IndexOf` from it. Add some more details, type it here as an answer, I would like to mark it correct.

Answer (score 4):

For "huge" strings, it may make sense to take a streamed approach and not load the whole thing into memory. For the best raw performance, you can sometimes squeeze a little more speed out by using pointer math to search and capture pieces of strings.

To be clear, I'm stating two completely different approaches.

**1 - Stream**
The OP doesn't say how big these strings are, but it may be impractical to load them into memory. Perhaps they are being read from a file, from a data reader connected to a DB, from an active network connection, etc.

In this scenario, I would open a stream, read forward, buffering my input in a `StringBuilder` until the criteria was met.

**2 - Unsafe Char Manipulation**
This requires that you *do* have the complete string. You can obtain a char* to the start of a string quite simply:

```
// fix entire string in memory so that we can work w/ memory range safely
fixed( char* pStart = bigString ) 
{
    char* pChar = pStart; // unfixed pointer to start of string
    char* pEnd = pStart + bigString.Length;
}
```

You can now increment `pChar` and examine each character. You can buffer it (e.g. if you want to examine multiple adjacent characters) or not as you choose. Once you determine the ending memory location, you now have a range of data that you can work with.

[Unsafe Code and Pointers in c#](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/t2yzs44b)

**2.1 - A Safer Approach**

**If** you are familiar with unsafe code, it is very fast, expressive, and flexible. If not, I would still use a similar approach, but without the pointer math. This is similar to the approach which @supercat suggested, namely:

- Get a char[].
- Read through it character by character.
- Buffer where needed. `StringBuilder` is good for this; set an initial size and reuse the instance.
- Analyze buffer where needed.
- Dump buffer often.
- Do something with the buffer when it contains the desired match.

*And an obligatory disclaimer for unsafe code:* The vast majority of the time the framework methods are a better solution. They are safe, tested, and invoked millions of times per second. Unsafe code puts all of the responsibility on the developer. It does not make any assumptions; it's up to you to be a good framework/OS citizen (e.g. not overwriting immutable strings, allowing buffer overruns, etc.). Because it does not make any assumptions and removes the safeguards, it will often yield a performance increase. It's up to the developer to determine if there is indeed a benefit, and to decide if the advantages are significant enough.

Comment: The main thing is **CAPTURING**, to capture one needs to look at the character level in a string rather than as a **WHOLE**. `Regex's` do not always solve the problem. @TimMedora

Comment: Where in my answer do you see any mention of a regex?

Comment: I was being proactive. I thought you could say, "use `Regex`". @TimMedora

Comment: Not at all. I'm saying, fix a pointer to the start of the string, read char by char by incrementing the pointer, and then when you find the matching sequence, capture the range of data based on the starting/ending value of the pointer.

Comment: Or with my "streaming" comment, you could read these large strings from disk or an HTTP source or wherever--character by character--and not incur the cost of allocating the whole thing.

Comment: Suggestion for @TimMedora: Since you have two separate approaches, consider two separate answers; then the community could vote on both and sort out what would be the more "commonly accepted" approach. This is not required, of course! :-)

Comment: C# does indeed have "native" support for pointers. It requires unsafe blocks, which is presumably why Tim called it "unsafe" twice.

Comment: Yes, unsafe code is an integral part of the language and well documented in the spec: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms228593

Comment: @PlatinumAzure - not a bad idea, though I've never done that for any answer. I think it would make more sense for a widely-visited question, which I doubt this one will be. I'll gladly accept a single upvote/downvote for the answer.

Comment: I used the term "native" just to clear out the sense -"unsafe code is integral part of the language". Indeed, it supports pointers, but that approach is "unnative". Don't call it native because it isn't. @JonHanna

Comment: Really, what is it, if it isn't native. Because when something is built right into a language, and directly maps to what is built into the next layer down, that's what we mean by "native".

Comment: It's unsafe code and that's why it's not "native". It may be "build right into the language", but you can not call it "native" because of it. http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/438868/Inline-MSIL-in-Csharp-VB-NET-and-Generic-Pointers - read the introduction of this article. @JonHanna

Comment: Of course I can call it *native*, that's what the word *native* means in the context of computer languages. Re-read the introduction of the article you linked to, and note that it's not needed to do the code Tim gives.

Answer (score 1):

There's an `IndexOf` operation which would search more quickly for `someChar`, but I'll assume your real function to find the desired length is more complicated than that.  In that scenario, I would recommend copying `someString` to a `Char[]`, doing the search, and then using the `new String(Char[], Int32, Int32)` constructor to produce the final string.  Indexing a `Char[]` is going to be so much more efficient than indexing an `String` or `StringBuilder` that unless you expect that you'll typically be needing only a small fraction of the string, copying everything to the `Char[]` will be a 'win' (unless, of course, you could simply use something like `IndexOf`).

Even if the length of the string will often be much larger than the length of interest, you may still be best off using a `Char[]`.  Pre-initialize the `Char[]` to some size, and then do something like:

```
Char[] temp = new Char[1024];
int i=0;
while (i < theString.Length)
{
  int subLength = theString.Length - i;
  if (subLength > temp.Length)  // May impose other constraints on subLength, provided
    subLength = temp.Length;    // it's greater than zero.
  theString.CopyTo(i, temp, 0, subLength);
  ... do stuff with the array
  i+=subLength;
}
```

Once you're all done, you may then use a single SubString call to construct a string with the necessary characters from the original.  If your application requires buinding a string whose characters differ from the original, you could use a `StringBuilder` and, within the above loop, use the `Append(Char[], Int32, Int32)` method to add processed characters to it.

Note also that when the above loop construct, one may decide to reduce `subLength` at any point in the loop provided it is not reduced to zero.  For example, if one is trying to find whether the string contains a prime number of sixteen or fewer digits enclosed by parentheses, one could start by scanning for an open-paren; if one finds it and it's possible that the data one is looking for might extend beyond the array, set `subLength` to the position of the open-paren, and reloop.  Such an approach will result in a small amount of redundant copying, but not much (often none), and will eliminate the need to keep track of parsing state between loops.  A very convenient pattern.

Comment: Agree, although you don't have to copy the string to a char[]. A string can be referenced *as* a char array.

Comment: @TimMedora: A string has an indexed property accessor of type `Char`, which is used with the same syntax as a character array, but a real array of `Char` may be accessed much more quickly.

Comment: Fair enough, I've only ever treated a string as a char[] with unsafe code...couldn't comment on the performance using indexer.

Comment: @TimMedora: I've not done such things in C#, so I'm curious: were you treading it as a `Char[]` (i.e. a `System.Array` object), or as a `fixed char[]`?  From what I understand, a `fixed` array is syntactically like a `System.Array`, but in exchange for faster performance one loses array bounds checking and the ability to pass it to code which expects a `System.Array` or other derivative of `Object`.

Comment: A `fixed char*` (essentially, the code in my answer). You are correct that you lose all of those things, but in return you usually gain some performance (how much really depends, can be < 10% - 100%+). You can still pass a pointer from method to method. I've used this approach mostly in code which does heavy string parsing (like an HTML DOM) or code which gets called thousands of times a minute like a Base62 algorithm.

Comment: One great example of safe versus unsafe is Bitmap manipulation in .Net. The safe methods are about 10x slower than the unsafe methods (which give a byte* to the start of the blob).

Comment: @TimMedora: I agree `unsafe` code can have some significant performance advantages.  My point was that if one wishes to avoid restricting code to full-trust environments, a managed `Char[]` will allow much faster indexing than a `String`.  BTW, with regard to bitmaps, I wonder why there's no nice Framework method (at least none I'm aware of) to copy bitmap data to/from a managed array?  Microsoft could certify the method as `safe` even if it used raw pointers internally, and it would seem to make much of the speed advantage of `unsafe` code available in limited-trust environments.

Comment: No argument...I just finished adding a big disclaimer to my answer about unsafe code. 99.9% of the time it's not the right solution (though big strings are a candidate). With regards to Bitmap, I imagine that there isn't that much demand for it. Heavy graphic work is usually done elsewhere, like XNA: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/centrum-xna.aspx

Comment: @TimMedora: I've never used XNA.  I've simply found myself in situations where the purely-managed approach was a little slower than I wanted and the use of array operations to manipulate pixel data would have fit well with what I was doing; if using a managed-array-to-bitmap routine would have doubled the execution speed, that would have represented a bigger execution-time savings than anything that could possibly be done with XNA or any other technology.

Answer (score -1):

You always want to use StringBuilder when manipulating strings. This is becwuse strings are immutable, so every time a new object needs to be created.

Comment: -1 Read his sample code, it has nothing to do with immutability.